# Login control to redirect to different pages depending on the query executed

Tags: c#, sql

I have two queries.. what I want to do is if the login control finds the username and password in 1st query table redirect it to seller page.. If it finds the un and pw in 2nd query table then redirect it to the dealer page. How can I do that? Coz it only checks the first query.

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        string user = Login1.UserName;
        string pass = Login1.Password;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select username, password, status from login where username = '" + user + "' and password = '" + pass + "' and status = 1", con);
        string CurrentName;
        CurrentName = (string)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        if (CurrentName != null)
        {

            Session.Timeout = 1;
            Session["un"] = Login1.UserName;
            Response.Redirect("sellerlogin.aspx?un=" + Login1.UserName);

        }
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select username, password, status from dealer where username = '" + user + "' and password = '" + pass + "' ", con);

        string CurrentNam;
        CurrentNam = (string)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
        if (CurrentNam != null)
        {
            Session.Timeout = 1;
            Response.Redirect("dealerlogin.aspx?un="+ Login1.UserName);
        }
```

Comment: What means "it only checks the first query"? Have you used the debugger? Always use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
Response.End();
return;
```

With your code:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    string user = Login1.UserName;
    string pass = Login1.Password;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select username, password, status from login where username = '" + user + "' and password = '" + pass + "' and status = 1", con);
    string CurrentName;
    CurrentName = (string)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    if (CurrentName != null)
    {

        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Session["un"] = Login1.UserName;
        Response.Redirect("sellerlogin.aspx?un=" + Login1.UserName);
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select username, password, status from dealer where username = '" + user + "' and password = '" + pass + "' ", con);

    string CurrentNam;
    CurrentNam = (string)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
    if (CurrentNam != null)
    {
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Response.Redirect("dealerlogin.aspx?un="+ Login1.UserName);
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What issue does that fix? OP says it "only checks first query"

Comment: genius :o Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Samsam - I'm happy to help you! Please choose my answer as the right answer and upvote ^^. Thank you!